# Short name for this site?

Tags: discussion, support

What's the right way to refer to this site, except the full name "Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange" or the URL "cstheory.stackexchange.com".

Personally I've been using "cstheory" in speech, and "CStheory" or "TCS.SE" or "CST.SE" in writing, but having multiple inconsistent names is incomfortable. Is there a preferred alternative?

Comment: In comments, you can use `[cstheory.se]` which renders as [cstheory.se]. It's useful on [cs.se], [math.se] or MathOverflow (which doesn't have a magic link).

Comment: Good to know, thanks! but my question was about all media of communication, e.g., in real life, in email correspondence, etc.

Comment: I think all the ones you mention are good except CST.SE which I don't think is used.